# Addressing women with "Sir"

Tags: terminology, vocabulary, professions

In movies, mostly around military personnel, female officers are sometimes addressed as "Sir" (Sometimes also followed by a "Um, ma'am, sorry..."). What would be the correct usage here if not using military rank? Are both" sir" and "ma'am/madam" correct?

Comment: It is never correct to address a woman as "Sir".

Comment: Please use a minimum of effort to find the answer yourself. It is easily resolved in both google and here - please do NOT ignore suggestions by the interface when asking at SE sites

Comment: Not unless she grows a beard n moustache.

Answer (score 3):

*Sir*, although originally signifying knighthood, has evolved into a modern honorific which is simply used to address a man in a polite/respectful way.

*Madam* is the female equivalent, which is the full form of the contraction *ma'am*.  It originated from the French term *madame*, which means "my lady".

Both are used to address someone formally.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_honorific#Formal_titles

Addressing a woman as *sir* is not really ever appropriate, because a knighted woman would have *dame* as her title and would be addressed as "Lady".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dame_(title)

Comment: This is an excellent explanation of the usage of both. But, the OP asks if you can use them interchangeably for a woman?  Can you revise/source to answer this?

Answer (score -1):

In the military it is question of regulation and the regulation is driven by tradition. For example, in the Hungarian army we use a very strange mix which contains both gender. Outside the military I would use "ma'am/madam".

Comment: This is fascinating, of course, but this is the *English* Language and Usage Stack Exchange. What you would say in Hungarian is very interesting to many of us, but unfortunately off-topic!

Comment: I agree, this site is about English language. However, if you read again what I wrote you may note I claimed that using of this form of addressing is driven by tradition and I showed an example to support what I claimed. On the other hand, language is part of the culture and both languages belong to western culture. To know how other cultures use their languages may result a higher understanding. In my opinion, it was not off-topic.